# How to solve the compiler error CS1061 'GridView1_RowCommand'

Tags: c#

**PROBLEM**: my local machine, it's working perfectly but when I uploaded it to my domain, an error occurred.

**Compilation error**

> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.customerregister_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'GridView1_RowCommand' and no extension method 'GridView1_RowCommand' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.customerregister_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 324:   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" Class="myGridClass" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" HorizontalAlign="Right" PageSize="10"  AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="OnPaging" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" DataKeyNames="ID">

**What I have tried**

Frontend code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" Class="myGridClass" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" HorizontalAlign="Right" PageSize="10"  AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="OnPaging" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" DataKeyNames="ID">
                            <RowStyle CssClass="gridCSS" />
                            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="gridAlternateCSS" />
                            <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridCSS" />
                            <Columns>

                                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" HeaderStyle-Font-Names="center" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Small" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerName" HeaderText="Customer Name" HeaderStyle-Width ="100px" HeaderStyle-Font-Names="center" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Small" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" DataFormatString ="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" HeaderStyle-Font-Names="center" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Small" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="withdepositconnection" HeaderText="With Dep Conn" HeaderStyle-Width ="50px" HeaderStyle-Font-Names="center" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Small" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="zerodepositconnection" HeaderText="Zero Dep Conn" HeaderStyle-Width ="50px" HeaderStyle-Font-Names="center" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Small" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" />
                                 <asp:BoundField DataField="OpenCylinderbalance" HeaderText="Opn Cyl Bal" HeaderStyle-Width ="50px" HeaderStyle-Font-Names="center" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Small" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="AmountDebit" HeaderText="Debit Amt" HeaderStyle-Font-Names="center" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Small" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="AmountCredit" HeaderText="Credit Amt"  HeaderStyle-Font-Names="center" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Small" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true"/>


                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit Details" ControlStyle-Font-Bold="true" ControlStyle-ForeColor="Black" HeaderStyle-Font-Names="center" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Small" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkview" runat="server" CssClass="gridCSS" ForeColor="green" Font-Bold="true" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' OnClick="lnk_OnClick">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
                                        <%-- <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1"  ImageUrl="~/images/edit-icon.png" runat="server" Width="15" Height="15"  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' OnClick="lnk_OnClick"  CausesValidation="false"/>--%>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" ShowHeader="False"  HeaderStyle-Font-Names="center" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Small" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
                    CommandName="Delete" OnClientClick="javascript: return confirm('Do you want to delete Customer this record?')" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>

                        </asp:GridView>
```

Backend code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
  {
      int ID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());

      if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
      {
          if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Open)
          {
              sqlCon.Close();
          }

          sqlCon.Open();

          SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
          sqlCmd.Connection = sqlCon;
          sqlCmd.CommandText = "Delete from CustomerRegistration where ID=" + ID + "";

          sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

          sqlCmd.Dispose();
          sqlCon.Close();

          GridView1.DataBind();
      }
  }

  protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
  {
      //int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.RowIndex);
      //DataTable dt = ViewState["dt"] as DataTable;
      //dt.Rows[index].Delete();
      //ViewState["dt"] = dt;
      //GridView1.DataSource = dtbl;
      GridView1.DataBind();
  }

  protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOmEv.png)